# Anular a tecla digitada pelo usuário

Tags: delphi

Num **Edit** normal do Delphi quero anular a tecla que o usuário digitou.
Se fosse no evento `KeyPress`, tranquilo, apenas atribuo ***#0*** para a variável *key*.
Mas estou e *preciso* usar o evento `KeyDown`. Nesse evento não estou conseguindo. Já tentei atribuir 0, abortar em seguida... mas sem sucesso.
Enfim, é possível? Caso seja, como fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O correto é controlar pelo `KeyPress`.

No `KeyDown`ou no `KeyUp` é para validações adicionais, mas, pode tentar:

```
  if Key = VK_DELETE then
  begin
    Abort;
  end;
```

Dessa forma abortamos o efeito da tecla delete.

ver mais em [dokwiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Virtual_Key_Codes)

Comment: Faz sentido não ser possível pelo `KeyDown`, tentei de todas as formas que conheço e não consegui. A sua sugestão pode funcionar em alguns casos, mas não em todos... se for para anular a digitação de uma tecla alfanumérica por exemplo, não funciona. Vou aceitar porque a primeira parte está certa. Obrigado.

Comment: Lembrou de ativar o ``KeyPreview`` do Form?